# Is NRDS compatible with Nagios Core?

Tags: nagios

I have (inherited) a Nagios Core server v 3.5.1. (that we use to monitor our own servers through mostly nrpe and some check_nt for windows). I have received a request from one of our clients to monitor one of his machines through our nagios. The client said he is expecting to get "**url, token and a config file**". A quick google revealed that there is a relatively new NRDS "method" - that I did not know about - that requires just these three things for client configuration.

I have spent some time trying to google a method how to connect and setup Nagios Core (not Nagios XI) with NRDS_win client. Is it even posible? All the tutorials I have seen mention NRDS Config Manager, that is installed into Nagios XI, no mention of Nagios core...

Comment: I have told my client it isn't - noone has proved me wrong yet - but please do...